# Login to PHP based website via Java Application

Tags: java, php, post, authentication, get

i searched this site for a solution to my problem but couldn't find a solution, please help

I'm trying to login to my company website with java which is designed using php.

There are many tutorials out there and i managed to scrounge some code and put it together but it doesn't seem to be working

```
package testphplogin;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class HttpURLConnectionExample {

private final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0";

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    HttpURLConnectionExample http = new HttpURLConnectionExample();

    System.out.println("Testing 1 - Send Http GET request");
    http.sendGet();

    System.out.println("\nTesting 2 - Send Http POST request");
    http.sendPost();

}

// HTTP GET request
private void sendGet() throws Exception {

    String url = "http://www.omnitech.co.nz/repair/login.php?";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    // optional default is GET
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //add request header
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    StringBuilder response;
    try (BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()))) {
        String inputLine;
        response = new StringBuilder();
        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
    }

    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

// HTTP POST request
private void sendPost() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("jsse.enableSNIExtension", "false");

    String url = "http://www.omnitech.co.nz/repair/login.php";

    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

    //add reuqest header
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", USER_AGENT);
    con.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");

    String urlParameters = "cLogin=<CENSORED>&cPsw=<CENSORED>&type=tbTech&Submit=Login";

    // Send post request
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(urlParameters);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'POST' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Post parameters : " + urlParameters);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }
    in.close();

    System.out.println(response.toString());

}

}
```

Here is the result

```
run:
Testing 1 - Send Http GET request

Sending 'GET' request to URL : http://www.omnitech.co.nz/repair/login.php?
Response Code : 200
<TOO LONG CENSORED>

Testing 2 - Send Http POST request
<TOO LONG CENSORED>
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

It just returns me to the login page

This is the HTML form that gets POSTed

```
<form name="form1" method="POST" action="/repair/login.php">  
    <input name="cLogin" type="text" id="cLogin" placeholder="Login">
    <input name="cPsw" type="password" id="cPsw" placeholder="Password">
    <div class="six columns">
        <input name="type" type="radio" id="tbtech" value="tbtech" checked="">
        <label for="tbtech">
            Technician
        </label>
    </div>

    <div class="six columns">
        <input type="radio" id="tbopr" name="type" value="tbopr">
        <label for="tbopr">Operator</label>
    </div>
```

Comment: It doesn't matter what the site is written in, webservers all basically do the same thing. So, in plain English, this is what you do: You send a POST with the proper credentials, it returns a page that also includes a session cookie in headers. You read those headers, and in subsequent requests, you send the cookies from the headers so the server sees you as having a session.

Comment: This question is too broad, but you may not be aware of that. Basically, most HTTP login systems work by setting a session by exchanging a cookie between browser and server. When you send a login form, the server verifies it and marks that session as "logged in" in its session store. Then, every time your browser presents the same cookie, it is considered "logged in". So you need to (a) check your PHP code to verify that this is how it's done in your case, and (b) Mimic this in your code by adding cookie handling (and using same cookie in all following connections).

Comment: I'm not sure if i am getting this, so basically i need to get a GET request which returns the variables i need to login with then send a POST request with the variables filled in?
The code on the website it a bit complicated for me